# batch file to create new subfolder in folder, move file to newly created subfolder, for all folders in directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am needing help to move files in my library.  I've searched and read for hours and can't find the proper solution, if any.

My directory looks like this

- D:Music\

  - D:Music\Name - Title\
  - D:Music\Name - Title\xxxx.jpg
  - D:Music\Name - Title\xxxx-type.jpg
  - D:Music\Name - Title\xxxx.xml

There are thousands of these entries in D:Music.  Folder names 'Name - Title' are all different.

I want to move xxxx-type.jpg to new folder named 'artwork' in the 'Name - Title' folder.  The files I want to move all end in '-type.jpg'.

The new directory would look like this:

- D:Music\

  - D:Music\Name - Title\
  - D:Music\Name - Title\xxxx.jpg
  - D:Music\Name - Title\xxxx.xml
  - D:Music\Name - Title\artwork

    - D:Music\Name - Title\artwork\xxxx-type.jpg

I have tried this:

```
for /d %%a in ("D:Music\Name - Title\*") do mkdir "%%~fa\artwork" 2>nul
```

This creates new folders in 'Name  Title' folders.   But obviously won't move the files.

I also tried this to create the folders and move the files:

```
@echo off
    for /f "delims=" %%a D:Music\Name - Title\ ('dir /s/b/a-d *.* ^| find /i "*-type.jpg"') do (
    if not exist "%%~dpaartwork" md "%%~dpaartwork"
    move "%%~fa" "%%~dpaartwork")
```

The above does nothing.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `*` doesn't work in `find`, instead do it in `dir` like this: `dir /s/b/a-d *-type.jpg`

Comment: So now I have:                                                                                          for /f "delims=" %%a D:Music\Name - Title\  ('dir /s/b/a-d  "*-type.jpg"') do (  if not exist "%%~dpaartwork" md "%%~dpaartwork"
    move "%%~fa" "%%~dpaartwork")      This is not working either.

Comment: Ah, wrong syntax, `for /f` doesn't allow specifying the path. Move it inside `dir` like this: `for /f "delims=" %%a ('dir /s/b/a-d "D:Music\Name - Title\*-type.jpg"')`

Comment: I tried as you suggested above.  No go.

Comment: Well, debug it by running the `dir` command separately from a command prompt, and if the output is correct then remove `@echo off` and run the batch file.

Comment: I ran dir from cmd and returned the correct files that I want to move.  I removed echo off and no go.  I removed the escapes (%), then ran 'for /f ......'   from command line.  This created a folder named "%~dpaartwork" in the root of the destination folder.  Something happened but not sure how.  Thanks for your help, I am really new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@echo off& SetLocal
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b "D:\Music\"') do (
    cd /d "%%~fa"
    if exist *-type.jpg (
        if not exist artwork md artwork
        move *-type.jpg artwork
    )
)
```

This will go through all folders directly in `D:\Music` and if there are some `*-type.jpg` files in that folder, it will move them into subfolder `artwork` (which will be created if it does not exist).

If you have folders with `*-type.jpg` files also in subfolders, you can use this

```
@echo off& SetLocal
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s "D:\Music\"') do (
    cd /d "%%~fa"
    if /i not "%%~na"=="artwork" if exist *-type.jpg (
        if not exist artwork md artwork
        move *-type.jpg artwork
    )
)
```

Comment: gordon - Your first example did not return anything when running @ command line.  I changed `dir` to `dir /a-d/s/b "D:\Music\*-type.jpg`.  This gave me the results I want to move.  But it ended with " The directory name is invalid".  No new folders were created.

Comment: It is suppoded to be run from a batch file. If you want to use it from command line, replace `%%` in code with `%`. I suggest you read `help for`.

Comment: gordon- my bad, in my comment '@ command line' should be '@ batch file'.  So I changed it to run @ cmd.  As a batch it did nothing. Prior to me changing `dir` it returned folder names only running at cmd.  Now it finds the `-type.jpg` files and tells me directory name is invalid.

Comment: What code exactly tells you directory name is invalid? Mine or the edited?

Comment: Gordon- your code did nothing in batch and returned folder names only in cmd.  After editing `dir` I get directory name invalid.

Comment: Gordon- when I add only`/s` (recursive) to the `dir` line of your code it works.  But if I run the batch file a second time, it puts the artwork folder one level deeper in another atwork folder.  Is there a way to prevent this?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, check if the folder name is `artwork`. If it is, don't do anything. That's what my second code does. You can try Aacini's code with a check for folder name.

Comment: Do you still have several levels of `artwork` folders?

Comment: Gordon- No, only one level of artwork folder.  It is working perfectly (both versions of your code)... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@echo off

for /R D:\Music %%F in (*-type.jpg) do (
   if not exist "%%~pFartwork" md "%%~pFartwork"
   move "%%F" "%%~pFartwork"
)
```

Comment: Aacini- this worked, kind of.  It created the artwork folder and moved the files.  But... it created over 10 levels of the artwork folder for the first file and even more artwork folder levels for the second file and so on.